# Can I convert this to a sub query driven query? As it stands it returns over a million rows due to LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

Here is the Query simplified:

```
SELECT
`Node`.`id`,
`Node`.`name`
FROM
`localhost`.`nodes` AS `Node`
LEFT JOIN `localhost`.`data_date_times` AS `DataDateTime` ON (
`DataDateTime`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`
)
LEFT JOIN `localhost`.`data_locations` AS `DataLocation` ON (
`DataLocation`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`
)
```

Are there any down sides to this VS a left join? Can I order the results for the overall query by returned values from the subqueries?

My stab at formatting this query:

```
SELECT
`Node`.`id`,
`Node`.`name`,
    (SELECT `data_locations`.`name` FROM `data_locations` WHERE `data_locations`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`),
    (SELECT `data_date_times`.`name` FROM `data_date_times` WHERE `data_date_times`.`node_id` = `Node`.`id`)
FROM
`localhost`.`nodes` AS `Node`
WHERE ???
ORDER BY ???
```

Comment: This transformation doesn't quite make sense. If the JOINs result in too many rows, that implies that some `Node` records have multiple `data_locations` records and/or multiple `data_date_times` records, which in turn implies that your modified query will give you an error along the lines of `ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row`, because you're using subqueries that return multiple rows in a context where MySQL expects a subqueries that return one row (or no rows, which gets `NULL`ified). If you don't care *which* row the subqueries return, use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Your first query only requests the `nodes.id` and `nodes.name` columns from your `nodes` table.  So, why are you joining it to the other tables?  The way that query is written you will get lots of duplicate rows.  If you can edit your question to let us know what you want to retrieve -- what you're trying to accomplish -- we'll have an easier time giving a useful answer.

Comment: Basically we have a table with "nodes" - they are containers with zero data types associated. We are trying to check all of the data type tables and see if the "node_id" field matches, and if so - pull all of the data.

There are 6 or so data type tables.

The LEFT JOIN is causing millions of records to be returned, but we need to be able to order by and of the results for example.

If this all seems odd, it is a query to be run in CakePHP that retains the data structure into an array, hence doing it all in a single call.

Happy to explain further via Skype or pay some $$$ for consulting.

Comment: So it sounds like you do *need* those millions of records to be returned? In that case, subqueries won't accomplish what you want, since they won't generate the millions of records for you.

Comment: Or is it an issue of, you're effectively getting an unwanted cross-join between `data_locations` and `data_date_time`? Like, a given node might have five `data_locations` records and ten `data_date_time` records; in such a case, your current query is giving you fifty records for that node, but really want you want is just ten records, with `data_locations` records being arbitrarily paired up with `data_date_time` records?